# Android: how to forcefully reproduce "OpenGL context loss" issue?

Tags: android, opengl-es, design-time

There's some possibility for an android OpenGL application of GL context loss while on background. So, to keep things simple, if you're got unexpected Renderer.onSurfaceCreated call - whoah, you're lucky. System wiped you out and you have to recover all you GL stuff from scratch.
One thing that rather bothers me and google documentation seems to keep silence about - how could one firmly and efficiently reproduce the issue during development?